# CSS: interference of 2 elements, doesn't work with z-index?

Tags: css

in my header I have a dropdown menu (green) that interferes with a sticky header (purple).
Sticky header is above the dropdown menu, so when I try to hover the different element of the dropdown menu, I lose it when it goes on the sticky header.

[image]

[image]

So for me this was an obvious z-index issue to be resolved with CSS, so I've tried:

```
#regularMenu .hasDrop ul.site-nav__dropdown {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
#prodForm.prod_form.prod_form_footer.sticky_addcart {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work for some reason

I've also tried these other selectors for the dropdown menu, without success:

```
#regularMenu .hasDrop ul
.hasDrop ul
```

If you want to test it by yourself, this is one of the URL product pages where I encounter my issue:
https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/products/collier-yin-et-yang

Any idea would be greatly appreciated, a huge thanks in advance :)
Pascal

Comment: just remove `z-index` from both..

Answer (score 1):

try this.

This is your css now

```
header {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

just change the z-index value to 9999;

```
header {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: agree OR : `.prod_form.prod_form_footer.sticky_addcart.top {z-index: 10;}`